# Jasper Server - MSWord Exporting Multiple Files

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

Would like to export word file - one file for each record.  Something similiar to Excel one sheet per page type option.

Jasper Does a great job with this in regards to generating the DOCX file - but it puts all pages in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Reports does not have a built in function to do this. It is designed to export one file at a time. What you can do is actually do this in your java code. It would require you getting your data, and looping through each row and exporting it yourself. You would be able to reuse your `JasperDesign` object though and not have to reinitialize it on every loop.